# MoreLikeThis in Solr to search text in document

Tags: c#, solr, morelikethis

Hello i'm interested in Solr module MoreLikeThis, but I don't know how to use it. I have one string and i wan't search similar text in documents so i do this:

```
        internal static List<SolrRecord> FindMoreLikeThis(int shopId, string myString)
    {
        var result = new List<SolrRecord>();
        //coś z moreLikeThis
        var query = string.Format("shopid: {0}",shopId);

        var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SolrRecord>>();

        var results3 = solr.MoreLikeThis(
            new SolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQuery(new SolrQuery(query)),
            new MoreLikeThisHandlerQueryOptions(
                new MoreLikeThisHandlerParameters(new string[] { "description" })
                    {
                        MatchInclude = true,
                        MinWordLength = 3,
                    })
                {
                    Rows = 10,
                });
        var baseDocument = results3.Match;
        var interestingTerms = results3.InterestingTerms;
        result.AddRange(results3);
        return result;
    }
```

I want to search the auction description that will include myString. Auction description i have without html tags, styles and other. Only text.

Can someone tell me how it works? I need to index my string to Solr ?

@edit
I've this

```
        internal static List<SolrRecord> FindMoreLikeThis(int shopId, string myString)
    {
        var result = new List<SolrRecord>();

        var query = string.Format("description: \"{0}\"", myString);
        var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SolrRecord>>();

        ICollection<ISolrQuery> filters = new List<ISolrQuery>();
        filters.Add(new SolrQuery("shopid: 77777"));

        var results = solr.MoreLikeThis(
            new SolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQuery(new SolrQuery(query)),
            new MoreLikeThisHandlerQueryOptions(
                new MoreLikeThisHandlerParameters(new List<string>() { "description" })
                    {
                        MinTermFreq = 1,
                        MinDocFreq = 1
                    })
                {
                    Rows = 5,
                    Fields = new List<string>() { "score", "*" },
                    FilterQueries = filters
                });
        result.AddRange(results);             

        return result;
    }
```

To parametr myString i add: "For sport driving" and in XML i have document whose in description have: "For sport driving mercedes each class".. in result i don't see this proposition but all words in myString are equal to description in this document.. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

First you should index all documents in Solr.

Then I suggest to play around by calling requests to Solr directly.
After you have get it to work you may write your client code.

An example query for MoreLikeThis could be like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=apache&mlt=true&mlt.fl=manu,cat&mlt.mindf=1&mlt.mintf=1&fl=id,score
```

See the documentation: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis

Comment: I read this documentation so many times and still don't know how it works... I edited first post

Comment: With easy /select and dismax I don't have any problems but with MoreLikeThis i have too much problem.. I'm trying understand this about 8 hours ^^ I wonder about out this idea to find similar texts from my mind..

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, if I understood your comment. Did you get any MoreLikeThis results, when you call the query by a url as I described in my answer?

Comment: No I don't have. `<str name="msg">undefined field title</str>`

Comment: Is the field (mlt.fl=myField) stored (stored="true") or are TermVectors (termVectors="true") activated in schema.xml?

Comment: Yes. Ok I think it's works fine. Solr find other similar document to the main document. It looks like this: `"referencenumber": "FULL_MATCH",
        "attributes": "[ograniczenie^1][ekonomiczny^0,9761512][jazda^0,7596395][bezowy^0,6832178][bez^0,6832178][beza^0,6832178]",
        "description": "Ekonomiczna jazda bez ograniczeń",
        "color": "Znaleziony tekst: Ekonomiczna jazda bez ograniczeń",` Description is orginal description auction, color it's my string to find in description, attributes are interesting term and here is my question. How can I choose word in terms to boost more ?